# jQuery form validation with password fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my form and for some reason it always validates true even if I don't enter any value in the field for password fields. If I change my control to text the validation works if I don't enter anything in textbox. below is my code. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here.

```
<form id="frmChangePassword" action="http://localhost/PatientAccount" method="post">
    <div class="row"><input type="password" id="txtPWD" name="txtPWD" placeholder="" style="" class="text focus" value=""></div>
    <div class="row"><input type="password" id="txtReEnterPWD" name="txtReEnterPWD" placeholder="" style="" class="text" value=""></div>
    <div class="row"><input type="Button" ID="btnChangePassword" Name="btnChangePassword" STYLE="" Class="btn-submit" VALUE="Change Password" onClick="javascript:ValidateResetPassword();"></div>
</form>

<script>
function ValidateResetPassword() {
    $("#frmChangePassword").validate({
        rules: {
            "txtPWD": { required:true },
            "txtReEnterPWD": { required:true }
        },
        messages: {
            "txtPWD": { required: "Please enter Password" },
            "txtReEnterPWD": {required: "Please re-enter password" }
        }
    });

    if ($("#frmChangePassword").valid()) {
        hashPassword();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can edit your original question to add that info. And you can also format your code easily with a button in the editor. And what is the `validate` method?

Comment: Don't post code in the comment area. You can format your code in your post and paste the codes there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help this will help you.

Comment: validate() is a method provided by the jQuery Validation plugin. It's a very complex and large method, not to be pasted in a StackOverflow question. ;-) More important is to link to the Validate API for anybody who needs to understand it.

Comment: thanks for code formating tips. I am still new to stackoverflow. I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bunch of little issues.

1)  You do not need inline JavaScript on the submit button to call the Validate plugin.  The plugin takes care of that internally with its `submitHandler` callback function.

2)  The submit button should be a `<input type="submit"`.  If you need it to be something else, that's going to require different code.

3)  The `.validate()` function should only be used to "initialize" the form upon DOM ready.  You incorrectly enclosed it within another function that's called every time the button is clicked.

4)  Since the `if valid` conditional is only called once when the page loads, and since the form is always invalid on page load, the `hashPassword()` function is presently never called.  If you want that function to occur whenever the form is valid, then just put it inside the `submitHandler:` callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#frmChangePassword").validate({
        rules: {
            "txtPWD": {
                required: true
            },
            "txtReEnterPWD": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "txtPWD": {
                required: "Please enter Password"
            },
            "txtReEnterPWD": {
                required: "Please re-enter password"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            hashPassword();
            form.submit();
            // alert('valid form'); // for demo
            // return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/zgwkR/

**Plugin Documentation:**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

**Official Sample Forms:**

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/